Is there a way to create a Google Analytics tracking event for Verint survey responses?
We currently use Verint to collect survey responses. I wanted to see if there is a way we can create custom Google Analytics or Google Tag Manager tracking events for every time a survey is completed, such as a survey_completed event. The goal would be able to match the survey responses to their website traffic.
I can't find any documentation on Verint regarding this so wondering if anyone has done anything similar.
